# Can't add foreign key on relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models:

```
class BracketMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :bracket
end
```

and

```
class Bracket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bracket_matches

  # Has a STI column
end
```

I am trying to add a foreign key to the table `bracket_matches`.

```
add_foreign_key :bracket_matches, :brackets
```

Raises the following error

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "bracket_matches" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_39684e0d9b"
DETAIL:  Key (bracket_id)=(122) is not present in table "brackets".
: ALTER TABLE "bracket_matches" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_39684e0d9b"
FOREIGN KEY ("bracket_id")
REFERENCES "brackets" ("id")
```

What am I doing wrong and why is it checking `bracket_id` on `brackets` instead of `bracket_matches`?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21295 It's a bug?

Answer (score 1):

`rails g migration AddFieldToBracketMatches bracket:references`
Check your migration file and then `rake db:migrate`

### Edit

In that case why not just `rails g migration RemoveColumnFromBrackMatches` , remove_column :bracket_matches, :bracket , rake db:migrate, then delete both those migration files and create the migration I suggested above

Comment: It's already in production with thousands of rows, so I can't recreate it and lose all data

Comment: Can u create a migration called RenameFieldInBracketMatches and to that migration file just rename_column :bracket_matches, :bracket_id, :bracket_id, foreign_key: true

Answer (score 0):

Add index:true like this

```
add_foreign_key :bracket_matches, :brackets ,index:true,foreign_key:true
```

Comment: Did not work. It seems like you are thinking of t.references and not add_foreign_key?